# Varying Einstein-Hilbert action through xAct gives extra terms

Tags: equation-solving, physics, packages, xact, variational-calculus

I am trying to find the associated field equation by varying this action:

$$S=\int d^4x \sqrt{-g}(\kappa \mathcal{R}+\Lambda)$$

This should give me the below field equation when I vary above w.r.t the metric $g_{ab}$,

$$\mathcal{R}_{ab}-\frac{1}{2}\mathcal{R}g_{ab}=\frac{1}{2\kappa}\Lambda g_{ab}$$

To do this using `xAct`, I use the following code:

```
<< xAct`xTras`

DefManifold[M, 4, IndexRange[a, d]];

DefMetric[-1, metric[-a, -b], CD, PrintAs -> "g"]

DefParameter[Λ]

DefParameter[κ]

VarL[metric[a, b], CD][κ  RicciScalarCD[] + Λ]
```

which gives me the required terms but with some extra terms. How can we get rid of them to find the required result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the xAct forum, the fix here is to declare the constants Lambda and Kappa with DefConstantSymbol instead of DefParameter.

DefParameter in xTensor declares a symbol that can be used as a parameter dependency, say as we use t in functions of time. Therefore derivatives pay attention to parameters. On the other hand, DefConstanSymbol declares a constant, such that all derivatives give zero on it. This plays the role of the Constant attribute, or the Constants option of Dt in Wolfram Language.